# Proble running multiple rails applications on different ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had 1 application running just fine on port 1000, and then i copied the project and built another application (using the first app as starting point) and i run the second application on port 1001 just fine with a different layout.

The problem appears when the 2 applications are running at same time (ports 1000 and 1001), they start interchanging the layout between the 2...

Ex: im with the window open on the application nº1 and it refresh and i get aplication nº1 layout...

Why this appends? and how can i keep both applications running at same time and seperate (not interfering with each other)

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: just a thought: did you check the browser address, are you not redirected to the other app by any chance?

Comment: How so could you elaborate on that, how can i check and fix that?  

1 is http://127.0.0.1:1000/  and other http://127.0.0.1:1001/